# Hide field based on multiselect field select using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drupal

I have a multiselect field called 'City'. I have two other fields Zip and miles.

On page load all the 3 fields - city, zip, miles will be enabled.

1. When I click on city field, zip and miles will be disabled
2. When I click on zip or miles city will be disabled

My code looks as below:

```
//when city is clicked, zip and miles get disabled 
        if( $('#edit-field-city-value').is(':selected')) //city field
        {
            $("#edit-field-zip-value").prop('disabled', true); //zip field
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-all").prop('disabled', true); // miles - option Any
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-1").prop('disabled', true); //miles 1st option
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-2").prop('disabled', true); //miles 2nd option
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-3").prop('disabled', true); //miles 3rd option
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-4").prop('disabled', true); //miles 4th option
         } else {
            $("#edit-field-zip-value").prop('disabled', false); //zip field
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-all").prop('disabled', false); // miles - option Any
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-1").prop('disabled', false); //miles 1st option
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-2").prop('disabled', false); //miles 2nd option
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-3").prop('disabled', false); //miles 3rd option
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-4").prop('disabled', false); //miles 4th option
         }

         //When zip or any of the miles is clicked, the city should be disabled
         if( 
            $("#edit-field-zip-value").is(':clicked') or
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-all").is(':selected') or
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-1").is(':selected') or
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-2").is(':selected') or
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-3").is(':selected') or
            $("#edit-field-miles-value-4").is(':selected') ) {
            $('#edit-field-city-value').prop('disabled', true); 
         } else {
            $('#edit-field-city-value').prop('disabled', false);
         }
```

Fiddle link: `jsfidle.net/#&togetherjs=bTCOvaMP8o`

My code is not 100% working. MEaning - when I select 'City' no event gets fired. Also when I click on zip or miles, no event gets fired. Any help to fix this?

Comment: Why all the extra work to disable each `<option>` and not just disable/enable the `<select>`? Also provide working html. Those images are worthless for debugging. See [mcve]

Comment: ahh ok I will drop a fiddler in a bit

Comment: added a fiddle link

Comment: Add the jsfiddle link!

Comment: Are you using webform module? If so, that feature is provided out of box. No need for custom code.

Comment: No. I am doing this for view filter fields

Answer (score 0):

you can do a catch all for "ids" so your code isnt soo long `[id^=edit-field-miles-value]`. Not too big on jQuery so you could add a eventListener to the actual checkbox like `document.getElementById('edit-field-city-value');` and if it returns true change the others.